# How i get the url from the last page visited php?

Tags: php, joomla

My problem is that, I have a table with values, when I pulse on one of the cells redirect to a cell details page, in the url I pass the id: "http://localhost/example?id=123456". when I back to the previous page with a cancel or save button does redirect to the previous page and get in id with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but when you pulse the back button in the browser I don’t know how to get that url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session system of PHP:

```
$_SESSION['page'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

To redirect to the last page you can use the header function.

```
header("Location: ".$_SESSION['page']);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is enough and you don;t need to store the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on `$_SESSION` too. just directly check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` val.

For the client-side, you can use `document.referrer` in JS. Also, it can be helpful for you to know these functions in JavaScript:

```
history.back(); //Go to the previous page
history.forward(); //Go to the next page in the stack
history.go(index); //Where index could be 1, -1, 56, etc.
```

- Notice: If you have some routing system that handles the URL dynamically on the same path ($_POST or ...) you may need a more complex solution based on your framework.